# Ubuntu Server sendmail to google email with same domainvwith server

Tags: ubuntu, sendmail, gmail

I am using ubuntu server version 11.01

and I use sendmail to deliver email.

I cannot received the email send from the server to Google services, which they are in the same domain name.

```
Content-Type: message/delivery-status 
Reporting-MTA: dns; mydomain.com 
Arrival-Date: Wed, 30 Nov 2011 11:01:18 +0800 
Final-Recipient: RFC822; cs@mydomain.com 
X-Actual-Recipient: RFC822; cs@mail.google.com 
Action: failed Status: 4.4.7 
Remote-MTA: DNS; mail.google.com 
Last-Attempt-Date: Mon, 5 Dec 2011 11:03:58 +080
```

Comment: I have no idea what your problem is. Please try to explain it better. What are you trying to send how from where?

Comment: I send email to cs@xyz.com(hosted at gmail) from my web server, domain name : xyz.com

Answer (score 0):

Read [mail hosted at Google, web server elsewhere](http://blog.postmaster.gr/2011/03/14/mail-hosted-at-google-web-server-elsewhere/)

Comment: We really do prefer that answers have content, not pointers to content. This may theoretically answer the question however, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Also, this community really frowns on self-promotion such as this.  Speaking as someone who also blogs, you don't link to blog-posts without effectively replicating the main points in an SF answer and leave the blog-post as the 'more info' link.

Comment: It was not meant as a self promotion. I could copy-paste the answer. Would that be acceptable?